# How to delete the last rule in a target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to delete the last rule in a target group:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

unfortunately the rule at the bottom, labeled "last" - I can't delete.

Anyone know how I can delete it? Maybe by making the rule above it as "Requests otherwise not routed"?

Comment: You cant delete the default rule. It is a catchall in the event the request doesnt match any other rules.

Comment: yeah I see, maybe I can make the last rule the first rule and then delete it? lulz

Answer (score 0):

you can not delete a default rule as per aws indications:
[image]